# Как вставить ссылку в div

Tags: html, css

Ломаю голову как вставить ссылку на страницу с описанием. Вот тут на фото подчеркнуто красным как бы хотелось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я многое пробовал, но там ссылка не появляется.

Вот кусок того места:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-name">
            <?php echo $entry_name; ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы действительно уверены, что общественность поймёт по вашему коду, куда там нужно вставить ссылку? Особенно, когда в нём переменные PHP

Comment: В том и дело что я не понимаю почему она не вставляется. Я бы хотел реализовать то что подчеркнуто красной линией на фото. На основном сайте нет этого. Это сделано в фотошопе :D

Comment: @PashaDark опишите словами, что именнo вы пробовали и что не получилось? Вам нужно вставить ссылку - `<a href="">`?

Comment: Да именно, но она не появляется там, то есть код стоит, но сайт не отображает изменений (

Comment: @PashaDark в приведённом вами коде `<a href="">` отсутствует, попробуйте просмотреть исходный код отображаемого сайта, может ссылка не спарсилась/не отобразилась.

Comment: Пробую все равно нет ссылки (

Comment: <div class="form-group required">
             <a href="http://masterskaya55.ru/privacy">Как правильно снимать мерки с ноги</a>
               <select name="recurring_id" class="form-control">
                 <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                 <?php foreach ($recurrings as $recurring) { ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $recurring['recurring_id'] ?>"><?php echo $recurring['name'] ?></option>
                 <?php } ?>
               </select>
               <div class="help-block" id="recurring-description"></div>
             </div>

Answer (score 1):

в чем проблема?

```html
<div class="form-group required">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-name">
            <?php echo $entry_name; ?>
          <a href"/some link">some text</a>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблемы нет. Нет достаточного знания :) А все что я бы хотел на фотографии красной линией подчеркнуто !